Is there a way to remove pixel segments between polygons made with stars function?
I have created a density map of fish locations in two separate ponds in R.
library(spatstat)
library(sf)
pondboundaries_poly <- st_read("pondboundaries_poly") #Imports pond boundary polygons
pondboundaries_owin <- as.owin(pondboundaries_poly) #Converts polygons to owin object
df_ppp <- as.ppp(df$geometry, W=pondboundaries_owin) #Converts data to ppp object with pond boundaries as window limits.

Which gives a warning that 27 illegal points were plotted and produces plot(df_ppp):
Then:
density_locations_stars <- stars::st_as_stars(density(df_ppp, dimyx = 600)) #Converts to a stars object for pixelation.

Which produces plot(density_locations_stars):

My question is: how do I remove the pixels between the pond boundaries? I'd rather not have to run these plots by individual pond unless I have to.
Ultimately, I'm converting back to an sf object: df_fishloc_density <- st_as_sf(density_locations_stars) %>% st_set_crs(26915) and trying to replicate something similar to Andrew Heiss' work shown here: https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2023/07/28/gradient-map-fills-r-sf/

That looks like a bug when st_as_stars converts a spatstat im object (which is what density returns). I have a reproducible example based on the nc data set and random points generated with st_sample. You could try cropping it to the polygons but the stars object seems broken in more ways than that. I'm also getting deja-vu on this, will report the bug and link here...

https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/727 reported now...

pls see the github issue for a fix

Thank you for reporting @Spacedman, and thank you for resolving, @EdzerPebesma!

As a temporary fix until you either install the github version or the new version gets onto CRAN, here's a copy of the modified function pulled from the repo with slight adjustments to work out of the package:
stars_im_fix = function(.x, ...) {
### see https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/648
###setNames(st_as_stars(as.data.frame(.x, ...)), "v")
    d = dim(.x)
    create_dimensions = stars:::create_dimensions
    create_dimension = stars:::create_dimension
    nd = create_dimensions(
        list(x = create_dimension(1, d[2], .x$xrange[1], diff(.x$xrange)/d[2]),
             y = create_dimension(1, d[1], .x$yrange[1], diff(.x$yrange)/d[1])),
        stars:::get_raster(affine = c(0.0, 0.0), dimensions = c("x", "y"), curvilinear = FALSE))
    stars:::st_stars(list(v = t(.x$v)), nd)
}

With that in your workspace, then:
density_locations_stars <- stars_im_fix(density(df_ppp, dimyx = 600)) 

should fix it.

Thanks a ton for going out of your way to resolve this! And thanks for posting the work-around until it's updated on CRAN. I was trying to follow the #727 fix, but being new to GitHub, I was getting confused on how to follow. All the best.
